# Always enable paste in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, javascript, paste

Is there a way where I can disable JavaScript from disabling paste in Google Chrome. I don't want JS to be able to stop my pasting into a field. I want paste to always been enabled.

Comment: Have you consider blocking the JavaScript file responsible for this behavior?

Comment: I would prefer not to have to investigate this effect each time.